# How to include a msi file in a Wix setup project

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I added one msi file in a setup project through Importfolder option in Wix as shown in figure.
Now if i build it.It gives following error:

```
 ERROR:

----- Starting C:\Program Files\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\light.exe "REDtrack_Setup.wixobj" -cultures:en-us -out "REDtrack_Setup.msi"  -ext WixIisExtension  -ext WixSqlExtension  -ext WixUtilExtension  at 12/6/2010 4:29:48 PM

Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Linker version 3.0.5419.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\Apps\REDtrack Setup\REDtrack_Setup\REDtrack_Setup.wxs(2334) : error LGHT0267 : Found orphaned Component 'REDtrackService_Setup.msi'.  If this is a Product, every Component must have at least one parent Feature.  To include a Component in a Module, you must include it directly as a Component element of the Module element or indirectly via ComponentRef, ComponentGroup, or ComponentGroupRef elements.
D:\Apps\REDtrack Setup\REDtrack_Setup\REDtrack_Setup.wxs(1685) : warning LGHT1008 : The action 'PublishFeatures' in the InstallExecuteSequence table is being suppressed.
D:\Apps\REDtrack Setup\REDtrack_Setup\REDtrack_Setup.wxs(1686) : warning LGHT1008 : The action 'RegisterProduct' in the InstallExecuteSequence table is being suppressed.
D:\Apps\REDtrack Setup\REDtrack_Setup\REDtrack_Setup.wxs(1687) : warning LGHT1008 : The action 'PublishProduct' in the InstallExecuteSequence table is being suppressed.
D:\Apps\REDtrack Setup\REDtrack_Setup\REDtrack_Setup.wxs(1688) : warning LGHT1008 : The action 'RegisterUser' in the InstallExecuteSequence table is being suppressed.

----- Finished

Error in light
```

How can i resolve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read what error message says? See what code was generated for you by this action (ImportFolder; is it WiXEdit software?) and make sure the components have at least one parent feature, etc. according to the error message.

Comment: yup i read this error msg but what does it means "components have at least one parent feature".Can we not include a msi file in a setup project.

Comment: I suggest you to start from here: http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/. Get acquainted with the basics first. And yes, you can include any file into setup project if you'd like it to be installed to the target system.